# Why using custom Events / an Eventbus?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, software-design

I work with a piece of complex Javascript software and try to understand how it's build. It's pdf.js, but for this question it doesn't matter. This is a question more in the direction of software design, not how it works in this specific case (that I can read by myself). I wonder why they use Events for example in the case of simple click buttons

Example:

```
appConfig.toolbar.openFile.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  PDFViewerApplication.eventBus.dispatch('openfile');
});
```

appConfig.toolbar.openFile is a Dom-Element, precisely the click button. So the click event dispatches an event `openfile`.

```
eventBus.on('openfile', webViewerOpenFile);
```

This Event triggers a function

```
function webViewerOpenFile() {
    ...do stuff
}
```

In some, but not all cases, there is one step more in the middle, that I do not understand at the moment: `Eventbus` creates a new clone event of the old.

```
eventBus.on('pagemode', function (e) {
  var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
  event.initCustomEvent('pagemode', true, true, {
    mode: e.mode,
  });
  e.source.pdfViewer.container.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

I really can not see the advantage of this complicated way of doing it. Why not just bind the function to the Dom-Element as usual, like so:

```
appConfig.toolbar.openFile.addEventListener('click', webViewerOpenFile);
```

Maybe someone can enlighten me?

Comment: That is done probably to add another layer of redirection. The button when clicked should open a file, but it doesn't specify how it should open the file so you can in the future easily modify all openfile events to be handled differently by only changing one line of code.

Comment: it's easier to test abstractions than raw dom-based events.

Comment: See also for explanation why it is introduced for pdf.js at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/7254

Comment: Oh there is actually an explanation. Should have looked for that before, thank you. I understand that this reduces the amount of dependencies drastically, but how a click handler can be inconsistent, I still have to find  out...